# Lazy quantifier and lookahead

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm working on a regex for validating urls in C#. Right now, the regex I need must not match other `http://` but the first one inside the url. This was my first try:

```
(https?:\/\/.+?)\/(.+?)(?!https?:\/\/)
```

But this regex does not work (even removing `(?!https?:\/\/)`). Take for example this input string:

```
http://test.test/notwork.http://test
```

Here is my first doubt: **why does not the capturing group `(.+?)` match `notwork.http://test`**? The lazy quantifier should match as few times as possible but why not until the end? In this case I was certainly missing something (Firstly I thought it could be related to backtracking but I don't think this is the case), so I read [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) and found a solution, even if I'm not sure is the best one since it says that

> This technique presents no advantage over the lazy dot-star

Anyway, that solution is the *tempered dot*. This is my next try:

```
(https?:\/\/.+?)\/((?:(?!https?:\/\/).)*)
```

Now: this regex is working but not in the way I would like. **I need a match only when the url is valid.**

By the way, I think I haven't fully understood what the new regex is doing: **why the negative lookahead stays before the `.` and not after it?**
So I tried moving it after the `.` and it seems that it matches the url until it finds the second-to-last character before the second http. Returning to the corrected regex, my hypothesis is that the negative lookahead is actually trying to check what's after the `.` already read by the regex, is this right?

Other solutions are well-accepted, but I'd firstly prefer to understand this one. Thank you.

Comment: The question is too broad. The second "doubt" is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat). As for the first one, you just needed to use a *positive* lookahead with a `$` as an alternative (`(.*?)(?=https?:\/\/|$)`). A `.+?` matches 1 char, and does not have to match more since it is lazy.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need a match only when the url is valid"?

Comment: About the first doubt: should I use `$` so the lazy quantifier can match until the end of input, right? Why is it not implied? I read your answer about the *tempered greedy token* and it's definitely more clear. I need a match only when the url does not contain other `http://`, whereas with my current regex I have a match when `http://` is included too. By the way, thank you for the answers.

Comment: Looks like you want something like [`(?>https?://\S+?/(?:(?!https?://).)*)(?!https?://)`](https://regex101.com/r/Uuf86f/2).

Comment: You hit the spot. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you seek is

```
(?>https?://\S+?/(?:(?!https?://).)*)(?!https?://)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Ehttps%3F%3A%2F%2F%5CS%2B%3F%2F%28%3F%3A%28%3F!https%3F%3A%2F%2F%29.%29*%29%28%3F!https%3F%3A%2F%2F%29&i=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.test%2Fnotwork.http%3A%2F%2Ftest%20http%3A%2F%2Ftest.test%2Fcom)

**Details**

- `(?>https?://\S+?/(?:(?!https?://).)*)` - an atomic group (allowing no backtracking into its subpatterns) that matches

  - `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
  - `\S+?` - any 1 or more non-whitespace chars, as few as possible, up to the first...
  - `/` - `/` symbol followed with...
  - `(?:(?!https?://).)*` - zero or more chars (as many as possible) that do not start a sequence of `http://` or `https://` chars.
- `(?!https?://)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there is `http://` or `https://` immediately to the right of the current location.

The `(https?:\/\/.+?)\/(.+?)(?!https?:\/\/)` does not work because the `.+?` pattern is matching *lazily*, i.e. it grabs the first char it finds, then lets the subsequent subpattern match. The subsequent subpattern is a negative loolahead that fails the match only in case there is no `http://` or `https://` immediately to the right of the current location. As there is no such a substring after `n` in `http://test.test/notwork.http://test`, the match ending with `n` is returned, the match succeeds. If you do not tell the regex engine to match more, or up to some other delimiter/pattern, it won't.

The tempered greedy token solution has been talked over a lot. The exact doubt as to where to place the lookahead is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat).